# displaying xsd:annotation comment if xml is not following standard

Tags: xsd, annotations, xsd-validation

displaying xsd:annotation comment if xml is not following standard :

Is there as way to achieve this. Would like to display the custom message documented in xsd to get displayed if restriction-rules is voilated

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand what you want, you should use a CDATA (Unparsed Character Data) block.
For example:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" ... >
  <xs:annotation>
    <xs:documentation>

<![CDATA[
    Here you write anything you want and don't care about XML syntax at all
    ...
]]>

    </xs:documentation>
  </xs:annotation> 
  ...
</xs:schema>
```

Anything between `<![CDATA[` and `]]>` will be parsed into a single string (text) exactly as written.

The CDATA-block is not XSD feature, rather it is a feature of the entire XML.

---

**Update:**

I've read your question again, and it seems you are asking something different.

You probably want that some your custom messages specified in your schema
for particular restrictions to be displayed when an XML file doesn't pass
those restrictions during the validation against that schema.

In other words, you want to improve the diagnostics messages issued by the XML validator
to make them more understandable to your users.

Well, in XSD 1.0 this is flatly impossible.

In XSD 1.1 there are more control about testing for various restrictions and conditions.
But even there I don't see how to specify any custom error messages...

Comment: Yes, I was referring to more of achieving your updated response from your answer. I would like the comment added in xs:annotation - documentation section to get displayed in xml when one violates some restricting condition specified for xsd element or attribute - specifically in IDE